# How can I fix this error "Property [discount] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I wanted to create a voucher code for my product in website.
I made a function that evaluation the voucher code and run it by ajax.

at first the function can find that the code is correct or not but can't decrease the price...and I get this error -

> "Property [discount] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."

my ajax codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
             headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
             }
         });
         $('.disbutton').on('click',function () {

               var datainput=$('.discount').val();

               var price=$('.priceforajax').text();

               $.ajax({
                    url:'/basket/discount',
                    type:'get',
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{data:datainput},

                    success:function (data) {
                          var discounts=data.percent;
                          if (data.discount=='notfound'){
                               alert('false');
                          }else if (data.discount=='found'){
                               alert(discounts);
                          }
                    }
               })
        })
 })
```

and it's my function

```
public function discount(Request $request){

    $discount=discount::where('code',$request->input('discode'))->first();

    if (is_null($discount)){

        return response()->json(['discount'=>'notfound']);
    }else{

        return response()->json(['discount'=>'found','percent'=>$discount->discount]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the **Discount** model.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the exact code that generate the error?

Comment: it is made by laravel the models is called by controllers. there is a function in basket controller and discount model was called in this function